# Rails is caching results from scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model that has a 'summary' scope that only fetches a couple important fields:

```
class Cupcake < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :summary, select([:id, :name])
end
```

If I call this scope and then later call

```
Cupcake.find(id)
```

I get the record with only the id and name attributes populated.

Is there some option I can pass to the find command to force it to go to the database?  Also shouldn't these be generating completely different sql statements and therefore activerecord would be forced to go to the database?

Note: I am using Rails 3.2.3 with the pg gem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the uncached method.  See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/QueryCache.html#method-i-uncached

As an example:

```
uncached_cupcake = ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
  Cupcake.find(id)
end
```

Hope this helps.